# Create a backup of every posts

Tags: django, django-models

I've developed my personal blog to learn Django, I would like to make a backup of every post on a second model. Below there is an example of my aim:

```
from django.db import models

class mainModel(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class copyModel(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeignKey(mainModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.text = mainModel.text
        super(copyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I create or modify a post into `mainModel` must be create a copy of it into `copyModel`. With the code above I can create a "post" but the save method from `copyModel` doesen't work.
Is this the right way?

Comment: The custom save method should be on the mainModel,  it should create the copyModel.

Comment: I've already do this without fortune.

Comment: Ohh, you  might be trying to copy before the save is complete.

I would consider a custom ModelManager method, and use that to create the copy after the data is saved in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override mainModel save method instead of copyModel

```
from django.db import models

class mainModel(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(mainModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        copyModel.objects.create(
            main=self, text=self.text)

class copyModel(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeignKey(mainModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Comment: With your code I see this error: `save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'main'.`

Comment: Please Check Now